# jCarousel not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, jcarousel

I have a jCarousel setup that has users click thumbnails to replace a larger image. It works fine in Webkit, but clicking the smaller thumbnails in Firefox opens the image in a new window. Thoughts?

Comment: Figured it out with help from @cryode. FF was giving a JS error saying that jCarousel couldn't determine the width or height of the images. Setting the "itemFallbackDimension" option when initializing jCarousel solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem Len was having was jCarousel was returning the error:

> Error: jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an
>   infinite loop. Aborting...

The error text is pretty self-explanatory. This is usually fixed by either explicitly defining the width or height of the item in HTML or CSS (whichever is appropriate for the element), or using the init option **itemFallbackDimension** when initializing jCarousel in your Javascript file. For example:

```
$('#myItems').jCarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    vertical: true,
    itemFallbackDimension: 150
});
```

The itemFallbackDimension will be the width if your carousel is horizontal, or height if it is vertical (IIRC).